# Updating UITextField with contact info selected from iPhone Contacts

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield, addressbook

After calling the PeoplePicker and selecting an entry from Contacts I can't seem to get the selected contact information to display in my view. Following Apple's Address Book Programming Guide for iOS, I display the People Picker modally and make a selection. Apple's code examples have the information being displayed in UILabels while I, because I also allow the user to manually input information into the text fields in the same view controller, need to have the information displayed in UITextFields. I've proved that the selected data winds up in the target UITextField (which is named "contactName") by printing to the console. The problem is, the selected data is not displayed in the view. When the user inputs manually, there is no problem. I just can't figure out how to transfer the data from the Address Book into the UITextFields in the view controller.

I've been trying for days, but can't resolve this issue. I'm probably overlooking something very basic. I'm new at this, so any help will be appreciated.

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{

   // NSString* name = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person,kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",ABRecordCopyValue(person,kABPersonFirstNameProperty), ABRecordCopyValue(person,kABPersonLastNameProperty)];

    self.contactName.text = name;   // 11/17/11

    NSLog(@"%@", name);
    // [name release];  Commenting out this code prevents the app from freezing when a name is selected from the picker.  11/25/11
    NSLog(@"%@",self.contactName.text);                // 11/17/11

    // 11/16/11 add additional contact info here

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)addToAddressbook:(id)sender{
    NSString *fname=@"firstname";
    NSString *lname=@"lastname";
    NSArray *arrayAdd=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"street Name",@"city Name",@"country code",@"zip",nil];
    UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ambani.png" ofType:nil]];
    [self addContact:fname:lname:arrayAdd:image];
}

-(void) addContact:(NSString *)firstname:(NSString *)lastname:(NSArray *)arrayAddress:(UIImage *)currentImage
{
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook=ABAddressBookCreate();
    ABRecordRef person=ABPersonCreate();
    //set Image
    NSData * dataRef = UIImagePNGRepresentation(currentImage);
    ABPersonSetImageData(person, (CFDataRef)dataRef, nil);
    //set FirstName and LastName
    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty,firstname, nil);
    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty,lastname, nil);
    //Add Address
    ABMutableMultiValueRef address=ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiDictionaryPropertyType);
    NSMutableDictionary *addressDictionary=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [addressDictionary setObject:[arrayAddress objectAtIndex:0] forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStreetKey];
    [addressDictionary setObject:[arrayAddress objectAtIndex:1]forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCityKey];
    [addressDictionary setObject:[arrayAddress objectAtIndex:2] forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCountryCodeKey];
    [addressDictionary setObject:[arrayAddress objectAtIndex:3] forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCountryKey];
    ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(address, addressDictionary, kABHomeLabel, nil);
    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonAddressProperty, address, nil);
    ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook,person, nil);
    ABAddressBookSave(addressBook,nil); 
    objABPersonViewController=[[ABUnknownPersonViewController alloc]init];
    objABPersonViewController.displayedPerson=person;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:objABPersonViewController animated:YES];
    CFRelease(person);
}

-(void) validateAndDisplayContacts
{
    if([firstName length]==0)
    {
        firstName=@" ";
    }
    lblName.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ : %@",@"First Name",name];
    [firstName release];
    if([mobile length]==0)
    {
        mobile=@" ";
    }
    lblPhone.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ : %@",@"Mobile",mobile];
    [mobile release];

    if([email length]==0)
    {
    email=@" ";
    }
    lblEmail.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ : %@",@"Email",email];
    [email release];
}


- (void)unknownPersonViewController:(ABUnknownPersonViewController *) unknownCardViewController didResolveToPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
    [objABPersonViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 6, [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated] is deprecated. If you try this, your code will work.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void) {
NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty)];
contactName.text=name;
}];
```